# Setting background colour for VideoView hides the video

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I am using a VideoView in my app and when I set the background colour with either the layout properties, or in the code itself, the background colour is laid over the top of my video and I cannot see it.

Answer (score 4):

`VideoView` extends `SurfaceView`, which relies on [`PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html) to cut a hole in the view hierarchy so that you can see a native rendering surface underneath. If you make it fill itself back in with a solid color, you will not be able to see the video. While the video is playing, you would not be able to see the background, so I assume you want it to be a different color while there is no video. In that case, use the `OnCompletionListener` of the `MediaPlayer` to change things... perhaps switch views or extend [`VideoView`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/VideoView.java) and override `draw` so that it calls the super class method while playing and does something different at other times.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);

videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to set the background color as usual, and on prepared, seek to the 1st frame and clear the background, aka.

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(
    mp -> {
      videoView.seekTo(1);
      videoView.setBackground(null);
    });
```

But, a known issue is there will be a black flash...