# VideoView - how to get tint attribute to work?

Tags: android

I have a VideoView in my xml, and am trying to use the tint options, but they have no effect:

```
<VideoView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:foregroundTint="#aa000000"/>
```

I've also tried with "backgroundTint", various color values, various tint modes, but never any effect. Is there some additional attributes that need to be set, or some limitations? I'm playing some local mp4 files, nothing special.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

VideoView extends SurfaceView, which relies on PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR to cut a hole in the view hierarchy so that you can see a native rendering surface underneath. If you make it fill itself back in with a solid color, you will not be able to see the video. While the video is playing, you would not be able to see the background, so I assume you want it to be a different color while there is no video. In that case, use the OnCompletionListener of the MediaPlayer to change things... perhaps switch views or extend VideoView and override draw so that it calls the super class method while playing and does something different at other times.

Font: [Setting background colour for VideoView hides the video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22402746/setting-background-colour-for-videoview-hides-the-video)